# Setting up a pre-deployment gate which validates status of linked work items

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-boards

I'm trying to setup a pre-deployment gate which validates that all the work items that are linked to the build have a certain status. Eg: `Approved for Deployment`. I thought I would be able to do this with `Query Work Items` gate but now I don't think it can be used that way.

The other option that I can think of is to use `Invoke Azure Function` or `Invoke REST API` gates that will take the releaseId and then use api calls to find the linked work items and then their statuses.

Is that the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Query Work Items** as a workaround since *it ensures the number of matching items returned by a work item query is within the configured thresholds*.

So you can edit the Queries validating status of linked work items to meet the requirements. The **Query Work Items** in pre-deployment gate like the following shows:

[image: Query Work Items]

You can also use **REST API** to add an **Invoke REST API** in pre-deployment gate like the following shows:

[image: Invoke REST API]

For how to get **Work Item Type States** and and validate status of work items, you can call the List REST API as follows:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/states?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Comment: How do i create a workitem query that only looks at the work items in the build?

Comment: You can refer to [Link work items to builds and deployments in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-deployments-control?view=azure-devops) to retrieve Azure work item deployment status.